# Flask ignoring config import

Tags: python, flask

My basic Flask app structure is...

```
/.env
/config.py
/app.py
/app/__init__.py
```

I'm using python-dotenv, and the contents of /.env are...

```
    FLASK_APP = app.py
    DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:XXXX/XXXXXXXXX'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:XXXX/XXXXXXXXX'
    SECRET_KEY = '0123456789'
```

```
And /.config.py looks as follows...
```

```
    """Flask configuration."""
    from os import environ, path
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
    basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))
    
    class Config(object):
        CSRF_ENABLED = True
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
        STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
        TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
        SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    
    class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
        FLASK_ENV = "development"
        DEBUG = True
        TESTING = True
        DEVELOPMENT = True
    
    
    class ProductionConfig(Config):
        FLASK_ENV = "production"
        DEBUG = False
        TESTING = False
        DEVELOPMENT = False
```

Finally, /app/**init**.py

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_migrate import Migrate
    from config import Config, DevelopmentConfig, ProductionConfig
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')
    
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    
    from app import routes
    
    print(app.config, flush=True)
```

When I `flask run` in the parent folder, I receive the output below. It runs in production mode, even though the printout of app.config shows that FLASK_ENV and DEBUG etc are being set.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    $ flask run
     * Serving Flask app "kwtr2.py"
     * Environment: production
       WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
       Use a production WSGI server instead.
     * Debug mode: off
    <Config {'ENV': 'production', 'DEBUG': True, 'TESTING': True, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION': None, 'SECRET_KEY': '0123456789', 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200), 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'JSON_AS_ASCII': True, 'JSON_SORT_KEYS': True, 'JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR': False, 'JSONIFY_MIMETYPE': 'application/json', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093, 'CSRF_ENABLED': True, 'DEVELOPMENT': True, 'FLASK_ENV': 'development', 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:XXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX', 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False, 'STATIC_FOLDER': 'static', 'TEMPLATES_FOLDER': 'templates', 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_NATIVE_UNICODE': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_ECHO': False, 'SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN': False, 'SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS': {}}>
     * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Thank you in advance!

Keith

Answer (score 0):

You did not import the `config` module in your application instance:

```py
# __init__.py

from config import Config, DevelopmentConfig, ProductionConfig

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(<your-config-class>)

# ...
```

Comment: Thanks Gitau, I've tried just that but am still greeted with "Environment: production" after "flask run".